# Unknown method "allow"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So I have this controller and method:

> Contorller/UsersController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;


/**
 * Jobs Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\JobsTable $Jobs
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Users->allow('register');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //Get Categories
        $getCategories = TableRegistry::get('Categories');
        $categories = $getCategories->find('all');
        $this->set('categories',$categories);

        $this->set('title', 'Registration');


        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'register']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }

}
```

> Model/Table/UsersTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator
            ->notEmpty('first_name', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('last_name', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('email', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A username is required')
            ->add('role', 'inList', [
                'rule' => ['inList', ['Employer', 'Job Seeker']],
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role'
            ]);
    }

}
?>
```

> Template/Users/register.ctp:

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create($user); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Create New User'); ?></legend>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type'=>'email'));
            echo $this->Form->input('username');
            echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password'));
            echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password',array('type'=>'password'));
            echo $this->Form->input('role',array(
                                    'type' => 'select',
                                    'options' => ['Employer'=>'Employer','Job Seeker'=>'Job Seeker'],
                                    'empty' => 'Select Role'
                                    )); 
        ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

> Entity/User.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * User Entity.
 */
class User extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = array(
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'username' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'role' => true,
        'created' => true
    );
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

So when I'm trying to access /users/register view, it gives me next error:

> Unknown method "allow": $this->Users->allow('register');

But if I remove next method inside of my Users controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Users->allow('register');
}
```

It works fine, but I guess it also must work with it as well. So what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Did you forget to read the docs? Since when do you do auth() on the model when this is a component called Auth? As in `$this->Auth->allow()`. Besides the thorough documentation all the tutorials also seem to use the correct code snippet ( http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html ).

Comment: @mark my mistake, but if I replace it with Auth next error appears:Error: Call to a member function allow() on boolean

Comment: We had this error before, didn't we? The property doesn't exist, the controllers magic getter for autoloading models kicks in, and there we go again.

Comment: As I understood I was not loading needed table correctly in previous case. But I don' get what I am doing wrong this time and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, I figured it out: $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => 'Controller',
        ]);

Comment: I just mentioned it so that you understand that this isn't limited to trying to acess models. The controller doesn't know what you are actually looking for, accessing non existing properties will always end up in the magic getter that is used for model autoloading.